# How to make an AFTER INSERT TRIGGER to change a date to getdate() if its null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know you can set defaults and constraints on a column but its an assignment.
This is what I have so far.

```
ALTER TRIGGER Products_INSERT
    ON dbo.Products
    AFTER INSERT
AS BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.Products
    SET Products.DateAdded = GETDATE()
    FROM products, inserted
    WHERE inserted.DateAdded = NULL
END
```

The problem is when I INSERT a row without specifying a a date it stays NULL and the TRIGGER never executes

Here is the question for reference.

Create a trigger named Products_INSERT that inserts the current date for the DateAdded column of the Products
table when a row is inserted that has no DateAdded specified (DateAdded is null).

Comment: Kudos, and an upvote, for identifying this clearly as an assignment.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1):

Almost there. You need to use `IS NULL` instead of `= NULL` in the `WHERE` clause.

EDIT: To integrate other suggestions... you also need to correlate the tables on their primary key, and should switch to an ANSI join. Table aliases also make it more readable.

```
ALTER TRIGGER products_insert 
ON dbo.Products 
after INSERT 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      UPDATE dbo.Products 
      SET    p.DateAdded = Getdate() 
      FROM   products p 
             JOIN inserted i 
               ON p.PrimaryKey = i.PrimaryKey 
      WHERE  i.DateAdded IS NULL 
  END
```

Comment: Not quite; at the moment there's no attempt to correlate the `products` table to `inserted` in the `update`. With this fix, it'll update *every* row in products whenever a new row is inserted with a null `DateAdded`.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the default of the column from is null to GETDATE(). So in every insert you made without the field you will have the date from the GETDATE(). Is no need for trigger to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a trigger for this.  Just use a `default` value:

```
alter table dbo.Products alter column DateAdded datetime default getdate();
```

Comment: `I know you can set defaults and constraints on a column but its an assignment` Question was asked to find a way to do it without a default constraint

Comment: @rickjerrity . . . A trigger should be a last resort if there is an alternative method for implementing the same functionality.

Comment: I agree, just reiterating the question. It sounds like they were specifically trying to do it using a trigger and having difficulties. Whether it's the best option in this situation or not is not relevant to the question asked

Answer (score 0):

When `Update TableA from TableB` you no need to join TableA

try this trigger its may work

```
ALTER TRIGGER Products_INSERT
    ON dbo.Products
    AFTER INSERT
AS BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.Products
    SET Products.DateAdded = CASE WHEN inserted.DateAdded IS NOT NULL THEN inserted.DateAdded else GETDATE() END --Check if date is null replace with getdate() stay still if it has a value
    FROM inserted
    WHERE dbo.Products.PK = inserted.PK --Primary Key
END
```

Comment: Nope - you should ALWAYS avoid updating rows that do not need to be updated. Remove the case expression entirely and add the proper where clause to check for null values. Mallorie's code is (now) the best example.

Comment: But i where Product.PK with inserted. PK isn’t it enough is inserted table contains any rows excepted your new insert rows pls explain its

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help I got it to work I was missing a JOIN between the inserted and products table.

```
ALTER TRIGGER Products_INSERT
    ON dbo.Products
    AFTER INSERT
AS BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.Products
    SET Products.DateAdded = GETDATE()
    FROM Products p JOIN inserted i 
        ON p.ProductID = i.ProductID 
    WHERE p.DateAdded = NULL
END
```